# Problem with Binomial numerical computation

Tags: bugs, numerics

**Bug introduced in 10.4.1.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2**

---

Using Mathematica 10.4.1.0 I have a problem with Binomial on numerical computations.

Both of the following correctly return `1.0` as the result:

```
Binomial[0.1999999999999998, 1/5]
(* 1. *)

Binomial[0.2, 1/5]
(* 1. *)
```

However, if I change the last digit to 9, it returns `5.0`, which is wrong.

```
Binomial[0.1999999999999999, 1/5]
(* 5. *)
```

Note that in general, `Binomial[x,x]` is 1. In this case, both arguments are very close to 1/5, so the correct result is 1.

Do you have the same problem? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: If you remove a single 9, it becomes 1. It has got to be a bug. Try: ```Binomial[SetPrecision[0.19999999999999996`, 50], 1/5]``` it gives me `0.9999999999999999872024250753568454`

Comment: The problem also appears in v12.1.1. `(Binomial[m, n] // FunctionExpand) /. {m -> 0.19999999999999996\`, 
  n -> 1/5}` gives `0.9999999999999999` so the problem is with `Binomial` rather than `Gamma`

Comment: A possible workaround is to wrap the first argument in `Rationalize`. Not sure if this is acceptable performance-wise.

Comment: The problem does NOT appear in versions 8.0.4 and 5.2. Can anybody check version 9?

Comment: @innaiz Same problem with version 9

Comment: @Riccardo Donati kindly report the issue to WRI https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer what the problem is, and when it appears. Did you contact Wolfram about this? If yes, did you get a response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the workaround to calculate

```
Binomial[a, b]
```

is:

```
Binomial[Rationalize [a, 0], Rationalize [b, 0]] // N
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Rationalize`

```
Binomial[0.19999999999999996//Rationalize,1/5]//N = 1.
```

Comment: Rationalize will not rationalize all real numbers, for example Rationalize[Pi // N]. So, to avoid unexpected results, we have to use Rationalize[#,0]& instead.